# What does "out of reality" mean?

Tags: meaning

> She is very smart. She is just out of my reality.

In the above example, what does "out of my reality" mean? Does it mean that she is too smart to be in a real word of this person? I tried searching the meaning of this expression, but it didn't seem to be an idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the speaker believes that the woman in question is too smart for him.  A similar expression commonly used is "She is just out of my league".